# Create a Dev Express "simplified regular expression"

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, devexpress

I can't seem to find any documentation on what a "simplified regular expression" is in the [Dev Express Documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMaskMaskTypeEnumtopic). I have a credit card field that validates the format of normal credit cards but some credit cards have only 15 digits and I can't figure out how to make a variable mask.

This is my current mask

> SaveLiteral = False,
>
> MaskType = Regular,
>
> EditMask ='[*3-6]{1}[*0-9]{3}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{4}'

I am guessing that the last variable

> '{4}'

needs to say something like

> '{3-4}'

but when I do this I receive an error on initialization of the object.

If I am reading this right it says [allowed chars]{how many} static char [allowed chars]{How many} ect

So that's why I think I need to figure out how to make a variable number for the last size.

Comment: Here is a page which should help - http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1499

Comment: Is the really a star `*` character in your credit card number ?

Comment: @Sniffer I didn't build this I am just trying to mod it. I don't know why they put that in there. Probably because someone might import a pre-masked credit card. I dont know though, ask them.

Comment: @Sniffer I read the page that Vijay posted. It looks like the * is a quantifier not a char

Comment: `*` is a quantifier when used outside of character class `[...]`, but it is a literal character inside as in your situation.

Comment: @Sniffer well once again I prove I know nothing about Regex lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match repetition of 3 or 4 times in regex, then it would be:

```
{3,4}
```

i.e.

```
[*3-6]{1}[*0-9]{3}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{3,4}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax of the quantifier is `{MIN,MAX}`.

So

```
[*3-6]{1}[*0-9]{3}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{4}-[*0-9]{3,4}
```

should be what you are looking for.

I wrote a blog post about this topic: [You do know Quantifiers. Really?](http://xisb.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/you-do-know-quantifiers-really/)

There is also the [official documentation about Quantifiers in .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx)

and the [general .net regex docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)